# Python Multiprocessing Async Can't Terminate Process

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, terminate

I have an infinite loop running async but I can't terminate it. Here is a similiar version of my code :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
test_pool = Pool(processes=1)
self.button1.clicked.connect(self.starter)
self.button2.clicked.connect(self.stopper)

    def starter(self):
       global test_pool
       test_pool.apply_async(self.automatizer)

    def automatizer(self):
       i = 0
       while i != 0 :
          self.job1()
          # safe stop point
          self.job2()
          # safe stop point
          self.job3()
          # safe stop point

    def job1(self):
       # doing some stuff


    def job2(self):
       # doing some stuff


    def job3(self):
       # doing some stuff


    def stopper(self):
       global test_pool
       test_pool.terminate()
```

My problem is terminate() inside stopper function doesn't work. I tried to put terminate() inside job1,job2,job3 functions still not working, tried putting at the end of the loop in starter function, again not working. How can I stop this async process ?

While stopping the process at anytime is good enough, is it possible to make it stop at the points I want ? I mean if a stop command (not sure about what command it is) is given to process, I want it to complete the steps to "# safe stop point" marker then terminate the process.

Comment: This seems strange: `i = 0` followed by `while i != 0 :` Since i is set to zero the while statement will never loop

Comment: Post the actual code you are using. What you posted is *not* a valid python program.

Comment: You don't need a `Pool` to launch a single task; a `Process` is enough.

Comment: @MichaelPetch you're right I was sleepy when I wrote that, it would be anything but 0. My real function is correctly infinitily looping.

Bakuriu - I know but actual code is really a mess, I believe question is simple, how to stop async process.

JanneKarila - I'm just learning multithreading, I will give it a try and hope terminate works for it. But even if it works, I still wonder why I can't terminate my async process or how can I stop it.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be avoiding the use of `terminate()` in normal operation. It should only be used in unusual cases, such as hanging or unresponsive processes. The normal way to end a process pool is to call [pool.close()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.close) followed by [pool.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.join).

These methods do require the function that your pool is executing to return, and your call to `pool.join()` will block your main process until it does so. I would suggest you add a [multiprocess.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) to give yourself a way to tell your subprocess to exit:

```
# this import is NOT the same as multiprocessing.Queue - this is here for the 
# queue.Empty exception
import Queue

queue = multiprocessing.Queue() # not the same as a Queue.Queue()

def stopper(self):
   # don't need "global" keyword to call a global object's method
   # it's only necessary if we want to modify a global
   queue.put("Stop") 
   test_pool.close()
   test_pool.join()

def automatizer(self):
    while True: # cleaner infinite loop - yours was never executing
        for func in [self.job1, self.job2, self.job3]: # iterate over methods
            func() # call each one

            # between each function call, check the queue for "poison pill"
            try:
                if queue.get(block=False) == "Stop":
                    return
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass
```

Since you didn't provide a more complete code sample, you'll have to figure out where to actually instantiate the `multiprocessing.Queue` and how to pass things around. Also, the comment from Janne Karila was correct. You should switch your code to use a single [Process](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) instead of a pool if you're only using one process at a time anyway. The `Process` class also uses a blocking `join()` method to tell it to end *once it has returned*. The only safe way to end processes at "known safe points" is to implement some kind of interprocess communication like I've done here. Pipes would work as well.